# Unable to access foreign_key relationship Table even with .join() in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Parent Model (CustomTitle) and a Child Model (Category). I only need a uni-directional relationship between the two tables (so no `backpopulates` here), where the Category has a reference to a CustomTitle.

Here is are my models:

```
class CustomTitle(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "custom_title"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    

class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "category"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    custom_title_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('custom_title.id'))
    custom_title = relationship("CustomTitle")
```

I want to **query** Categories that **contain a specific string** from Custom Titles:

```
categories_with_hello = db.session.execute(db.select(Category).join(Category.custom_title).filter(Category.custom_title.name.contains("hello")))
```

However this keeps giving me the error:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Category.custom_title has an attribute 'name'

I've also tried various permutations:

```
db.session.execute(db.select(Category).join(CustomTitle).filter(...)

db.session.execute(db.select(Category).join(Category.custom_title.name).filter(...)
```

But the same error keeps happening.

The official SQLAlchemy docs suggests that [simple joins should be possible](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#simple-relationship-joins), so I'm a little confused why what I have is not working properly?